# how to insert data in mysql table using sequeilze in express.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I try to insert data data in mysql table with sequelize but it insert null instead of value

i m trying following below code in my file userController.js

```
var db = require('../../../../config/db');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
TBL_USERS = db.connection.define('users');
var usersController = {
register : function(req,res,next){
      db.connection.sync().then(function(){
        TBL_USERS.create({
            username:req.body.username,
            email:req.body.email,
            password:bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password),
            role_id:2
        }).then(function(insertResult){
                //console.log("INSERT...............",insertResult);
                let send_data = {success:true,status:200,message:"success",data:insertResult};
                return res.json(send_data);
        })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error("query error =>",err);
                return ReE(err, 200,' register fail1',err);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.error("sync error =>",err);
            return ReE(err, 200,'register fail2',err);
        });
}

module.exports = usersController;
```

it return `success` `message` , but it only inserted `field_id`, `createdAt` and `updatedAt`

NOTE: i already validate all value with `express-validator` so i didn't define in

```
TBL_USERS = db.connection.define('users');
```

please help me to resolve this

Comment: Are you using body parser ?
Try to log `req.body` and see if your expected values show up

Answer (score 1):

Need to define data types in **users.js** or your database model file. add two lines as bellow

```
username: DataTypes.STRING,
password: DataTypes.STRING
```

There is no reason  to not working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to define schema with field name of table